# Scrapy callback problem: to scrape the follow-up page of an item I need this item's (auto_increment) ID in the database

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to do the following:

1. scrape some items (which include URLs) from some page.
2. save each item to a mysql database
3. get the (auto_increment) ID of the previously added record
4. scrape the page pointed to by the URL above (#1)
5. save all items on this page with a reference (foreign key) to the ID defined in #3

That looks to me like a very common problem which should have a reasonably simple solution.

The "item_scraped" signal looked like the obvious solution since it provides a callback for when an item has been fully processed.

However, it appears that it's impossible to start another Request from within the callback.

I read here that some people suggested using Spider Middlewares but I don't see how, especially since Spider Middlewares are not supposed to start Requests themselves.

I'm using Scrapy 2.6.2 on Python 3.8.

Thanks for your help.

My simplified code below, without error processing etc.

The spider

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import signals

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'MySpider'
    allowed_domains = ['www.somedomain.com']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.somedomain.com/someurl/', 
        ]

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        spider = cls()
        # requests the callback once an item is scraped
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.item_scraped, signals.item_scraped)
        return spider

    def parse(self, response):
        for node in response.xpath(".//tr/td[@class='foo']"):
            yield {
                'a': ...
                'b': ...
                'url': ...
            }

    def item_scraped(self, item, response, spider):
###
### UNFORTUNATELY THIS IS NOT POSSIBLE
###
        # forwards the new ID as a meta variable
        yield Request(item['url'], meta={'id':item['id']}, callback=self.parse_page)

    def parse_page(self, response):
        for node in response.xpath("//div[@class='soemthing']//a"):
            yield {
                'id': response.meta['id'],
                'title': ...
            }
```

And the pipeline:

```
import mysql.connector

class WinebotPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.conf = {'host': ..., 'user': ..., 'password': ..., 'database': ...}
        self.connection = self.mysql_connect()
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
    
    def mysql_connect(self):
        return mysql.connector.connect(**self.conf)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        sql = "insert into `some_table` (`a`, `b`, `url`) values (%s, %s, %s)" 
        self.cursor.execute(sql, list(item.values()))
        self.connection.commit()

        # id of last inserted item
        item['id'] = self.cursor.lastrowid
        return item
```

Comment: maybe first scrape all needed data (from pages and subpages) and later try to write it in database.

Comment: Like @furas mentioned you are better of passing the information from the first parse method that you need to the second parse method and then once you have all the info collected then yield it to the pipeline where you can save to the DB

Answer (score 0):

An easier way of doing this would be to get all of the info from the first page then use the url to yield a new request with your `parse_page` method as the callback and the scraped data as the callback kwargs.  Then once you have scraped the necessary info from the second url you can add it to the results from the first page and yield the completed item.  Then you can do all of your database entries all at once.

Spider

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import signals

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'MySpider'
    allowed_domains = ['www.somedomain.com']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.somedomain.com/someurl/', 
        ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for node in response.xpath(".//tr/td[@class='foo']"):
            cb_kwargs = {'a': ..., 'b': ...,   'url': ...}
            yield scrapy.Request(cb_kwargs['url'], 
                                 callback=self.parse_page, 
                                 cb_kwargs=cb_kwargs)
            

    def parse_page(self, response, **kwargs):
        for node in response.xpath("//div[@class='soemthing']//a"):
            kwargs.update({'title': ...})
            yield kwargs
```

Pipeline

```
import mysql.connector

class WinebotPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.conf = {'host': ..., 'user': ..., 'password': ..., 'database': ...}
        self.connection = self.mysql_connect()
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
    
    def mysql_connect(self):
        return mysql.connector.connect(**self.conf)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        sql = "insert into `some_table` (`a`, `b`, `url`, 'title') values (%s, %s, %s, %s)" 
        self.cursor.execute(sql, list(item.values()))
        self.connection.commit()
        return item
```

Comment: Ah, well, thank you for this. The thing is that it's a bit more complicated. On the first page ("page1") we are going to be scraping some info that will go into "table1" and some auto_incremented ID is going to be generated. Then we'll navigate to some url (found in page1) which will give us a few dozens other scrapable items which will be stored in "table2" with a reference (foreign_key) to "table1" through the ID generated in the first insert. I can see how to do it with your proposal if we're able to pass a full hierarchy of objects in kwargs, but it might be a bit messy.

Comment: at the moment I'm doing it by calling self.crawler.engine.crawl(<new Request>) in the "item_scraped" signal callback, but I don't know yet if it really works. Seems that the spider is closed before the Requests are really processed

Comment: @WolfD. Well if you are able to get the foreign key in the parse method then you could just pass that in the cb_kwargs.  But if you found a way that works then sounds like you got it figured out already.

Comment: I need to go through the pipeline and save the first "page1" item to get the ID, and the pipeline doesn't provide a callback, that's the whole point ^^

Comment: the whole self.crawler.engine.crawl(<new Request>) sound kind of hacky and it might not even work. I can see how I could use your idea to store all the info in a hierarchical object and then pass the whole thing to a pipeline which would do the job but as I said it's going to be very messy. I was thinking that a lot of people must have run into the same problem...